# Can storing structs in a Dictionary (vs. objects) help me?

Tags: c#, struct, garbage-collection, heap-memory

If I understand correctly, then `struct`s are stored on the stack - unless they are referenced by an object, e.g. as a member, that is stored on the heap.

Will the Garbage Collection collect the `struct`, simply as part of the object - or must it handle the struct explicitly?

Background: I have a Dictionary with items that are currently `class`es and I'm considering changing them to `struct`s. I'm aware that there is a price when passing the `struct` as parameters (because all members must basically be copied), but I'm hoping to reduce GC pressure.

Comment: Why do you think you are having an issue with the GC?  I don't think you will see any difference between a struct and a class in this case

Comment: @NPearson: I'm running in app with a very tight loop (60 FPS) and am trying to eliminate Garbage Collection as much as possible. This will require quite some refactoring and I'm trying to judge where I should begin looking and changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A long time ago, some wrote something about `struct` instances being stored on the stack, and this mis-information has stuck.  What makes value types special is how they interact with assignment operations.  When you assign a reference type instance to a variable (or pass it around as a method parameter), the *reference* is copied.  When you do it with a struct instance, the *value* of the struct is copied.

If you have a collection of value-type objects, what happens is that the slot for storing each object is the size of the object, not the size of reference to an object.

On a 32-bit application, a `List<int>` will take up the same amount of space (for the ints, not for the list) as a `List<SomeRandomClass>`.  But, it will be about half the size of a `List<long>`

When you create a `Dictionary<int, int>`, the ints get copied into the space allocated for the dictionary data.  When you create a `Dictionary<string, SomeRandomClass>`, then the references to the objects will get copied in instead.

Value types are never garbage collected - though object instances that contain struct instances will be garbage collected.  The GC doesn't care that an object to be collected has ints, DateTimes or references to SomeRandomClass or whatever within the object.

Reading @EricLippert's blog about structs/value types can be an eye-opener: https://ericlippert.com/category/value-types/

> **An aside:**
>
> Here's the link that points out the fallacy that structs exist on the stack: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229017(v=vs.100).  *"Value types are allocated on the stack or inline and are deallocated when they go out of scope"*.
>
> That is wrong.  It's frustrating that that statement is still on Microsoft's site 9 years later.
>
> Consider this code.  Every one of those member fields is a struct/value type, and everyone of them will be allocated on the managed heap for every instance of class `X` (and eventually garbage collected):

```
public class X {
    public int A;
    public long B;
    public DateTime C;
}
```

**As to your question**

*"I have a Dictionary with items that are currently classes and I'm considering changing them to structs. I'm aware that there is a price when passing the struct as parameters (because all members must basically be copied), but I'm hoping to reduce GC pressure."*

Don't forget that if you change things to structs, you aren't passing around references, you are passing around values.  If you add something to a dictionary and then change that something, what's in the dictionary will not change.  You need to think differently with structs (and, to be safe, you should make your structs immutable so you don't get into that kind of *easy to mess up* situation.)

And, *GC Pressure* is a complicated subject.  Are you worried about the dictionary or its contents.  If an object is long-lived (long enough to end up in Gen2 GC-land), then whether it's copied into the dictionary or it's own GC-able object shouldn't matter to much.

If you are worried about GC pressure, look around and make sure you aren't spitting out garbage objects inadvertently.  Examples of doing this are concatenating strings (particularly in a loop), building up large collections of objects into a list that you didn't pre-size.  Things like that.

Comment: "Value types are never garbage collected" and the remainder of the paragraph are what I wanted to know! Thanks!

Comment: To be fair to the documentation, you referenced an old page which has since been replaced with clarifications on how structs are managed - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct